# How to represent random json object in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm using the following library in my Android app -> [Google/Gson.](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
I can't figure out how to represent the following json String into a proper class to abstract it.

```
"random_chunks": [
    {
        "2013-01-01T10:00:00+00:00": {
            "available": 61,
            "in_inventory": 61,
            "in_service": 61,
            "percent_in_inventory_available": 100,
            "percent_in_service_available": 100
        }
    },
```

Basically we have an array named "random_chunks" which contains an object with a dynamic name "2013-01-01T10:00:00+00:00".

Here is what I was thinking:

```
public class RandomChunks {
    @SerializedName("random_chunks")
    private foo[] chunks;

    public class foo extends Object {
        // Here is where I get stuck
}
```

How do I target this random name? I can't say @SerializedName("some random string"). Thoughts?

Comment: 2 questions: can you change the json that you get? and do you NEED to use json? this would work easily if you just did it manually using the built-in json libraries.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the json that I get and yes I have to use json. It's a rails server and we're forced to use REST services

Comment: my mistake. i meant to ask to you need to use GSON. i prefer to just use the JSONObject/JSONArray that are built in.

Comment: ah, I don't have to but it's already heavily integrated into the code base now. The GSON library actually contains the JsonArray object and I was wondering if I could use it for this issue somehow.

Comment: GSON is great for serializing/deserializing, but I don't think you can  use it with a dynamic key. if you could change the json, this would be easy, but i don't think you can deserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is a bit weird, condensed:

```
"random_chunks": [
{
    "2013-01-01T10:00:00+00:00": { } 
} , 
.... ]
```

It would seem to me that the more natural way to express this is using the fields directly:

```
 "random_chunks": {
    "2013-01-01T10:00:00+00:00": { },
    "2012-01-01T10:00:00+00:00": { },
    ...
 }
```

The JSON above is a Map, that is `randomChunks = Map<String, Stuff>`

In your case, since you can't change the format, I believe it would be possible (but not very clean) to represent it as an array of maps:

```
 private Map<String, Stuff>[] weirdObjects;
```

In reality, all of these Maps would be very boring and have a single key, the one field you're looking for. It's not the most efficient way to represent it, but it seems like that's what you're getting.

Note: I'm not *that* familiar with GSON, so I'm not sure if it can deal with that. Jackson can though.